# Optimization of MS Access query for Oracle (ODBC)

Tags: oracle, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have an MS Access application that sends a query to Oracle and saves the results to a table in Access or directly exports to XLS.

For same query output 1408 rows it takes seconds below:

- In MS Access Application: 98 seconds
- In SQL Developer: 7 seconds

Access uses ODBC to connect to Oracle (I dont know if sql developer uses same driver).

_EXPORT_QUERY is access query which refers to pass-through query Oracle because of function DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet which allows only export access query. pass-through query doesn't refer to ODBC linked tables.

In Access code I use:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "_EXPORT_QUERY", path, True 'Exp"
```

*_EXPORT_QUERY* is Query which refers to Oracle Query

I tried to save query to table and then export – it doesnt help – still long time. I am looking for advice on how I might speed up the process in Access.

Comment: We need more information regarding _EXPORT_QUERY. Does it refer to ODBC linked tables? If so, does it refer *only* to those ODBC linked tables (no local tables or other saved queries)? Does it use any user-defined Access functions (implemented in VBA)? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: Please advice me. I already edited post.

Comment: *"DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet which allows only export access query"* - I just confirmed that I can export the results of a pass-through query directly from Access 2010 to an .xls file using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` and Oracle's ODBC driver ("Oracle in XE", v10.02.00.01). What version of Access are you using? Which ODBC driver are you using and what version is it?

Comment: I am using access 2003 and when I used DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet I got error (I read information on microsoft site and there was mentioned its not possible in access 2003). I use driver: "Oracle in OraClient10g_home1" (even on others Pc's I use 11g and same result).